# Is it always safe to `rebase --skip` commits that don't show any changes during a rebase?

Tags: git, rebase, pull-request, skip, merge-conflict-resolution

When working on pull requests they often fall behind `master` before I am able to complete them. Often the PRs end up with several conflicts in them, which I typical resolve by doing a rebase of `master` onto my PR branch. This works most of the time, but sometimes a conflict appears that I can't seem to fix with a rebase. I have noticed when this happens I get a lot of empty commits, which halts the rebasing and prints out a message:

```
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty
```

I don't really need to have empty commits, so I would prefer to just drop the commit altogether. If I run `git status` after I see this message I get the following:

```
You are currently rebasing branch 'PR-branch' on 'some-master-commit'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        untracked-file

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Since `git status` doesn't show any files changed, and I don't want to add the untracked files I would like to skip commit. But I only want to skip it if it is safe to do so. **Is there ever a case where skipping an empty commit in a rebase like this will cause me to lose data?**

I suspect this may have something to do with my unresolvable conflicts in my PRs. Any thoughts on this?

NOTE: I do have one untracked file in the directory containing the repository. I need it to remain untracked.

Comment: If you skip an empty commit during rebase and then for any reason do the rebase again, you'll get the same problem again.  I wouldn't advise skipping empty commits.  I don't think there is any "data" loss but you lose metadata, i.e. the (empty) commit information won't be retained.

Comment: Btw, if you have a file lying around inside the repo which you don't want tracked but can't move or delete, you could consider adding it to your .gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

An empty commit doesn't change any of the files in your project. It points to the same `tree` as does its parent. Therefore, it is safe to skip. The only thing you *will* lose is the commit message (and author information) of that commit.